# SQL Server Convert text from english to other language via an sp or function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in sql server which stores some text in english (in nvarchar column).

I have to create a stored procedure to which I will pass a language (Hindi,Gujarati,Arabic) as a parameter & it will return me data converted to that language from English.

I understand that best way would be to store data in those languages in different columns but I cannot do it & want to rely on sql server.

Is there some utility or function which will help me accomplish this.

Looking For Starters or ideas..

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2013/05/04/language-translation-in-sql-server-using-bing-translator-apis-sql-clr/

Comment: You have to use some kind 'language' table, containing all translations (for every context, btw) - you can't rely on any translation service, because you will have serious errors, invalid translations (these depend on context, language semantics, words multiple meanings, idioms and whatnot else).

Comment: @Arvo this will work in situations where I have a limited set of actions & words known before hand else I will require a language expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql-Server cannot translate from one language to another language, but you can use external tools for that, please look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2013/05/04/language-translation-in-sql-server-using-bing-translator-apis-sql-clr/

or you can create a wrapper for google translator: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic819515-386-1.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class Translator {
 /// <summary>
 /// Translates the text.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="input">The input.</param>
 /// <param name="languagePair">The language pair.</param>
 /// <returns></returns>
 public static void Main(string[] args) 
 {
  TranslateText(args[1], args[2]);
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Translate Text using Google Translate
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="input">The string you want translated</param>
 /// <param name="languagePair">2 letter Language Pair, delimited by "|". 
 /// e.g. "en|da" language pair means to translate from English to Danish</param>
 /// <param name="encoding">The encoding.</param>
 /// <returns>Translated to String</returns>
 public static string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair) 
 {
  string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);

  string result = String.Empty;

  using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
  {
   webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7;
   result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
  }

  Match m = Regex.Match(result, "(?<=<div id=result_box dir=\"ltr\">)(.*?)(?=</div>)");
  if (m.Success) result = m.Value;

  return result;
 }
}
```

but be carefull, Google will block you in an instant if you hit their servers with too many requests per minute.

Comment: This should be a comment