# Calculated field in different language

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to create a calculated field in SQL table which automatically converts LATIN to Chinese, Arab characters? 
Example:

```
FName | LName  | FNameChinese           |
John  | Martin | John in Chinese letters|
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, do you have a function that performs translation? SQL Server doesn't know how to say John in Chinese.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Convert text from english to other language via an sp or function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735662/sql-server-convert-text-from-english-to-other-language-via-an-sp-or-function)

Comment: You could use your own select query and use select translate, mapping the alphabet in English to Chinese etc. https://www.w3resource.com/sql/character-functions/translate.php
But as far as what you want no there is no in built function to translate languages, you would have to translate yourself and map it etc.

Comment: You'll have to define what "John in Chinese letters" is first. There's nothing of the sort built into SQL Server. Transliterating text is not generally simple to do, and doubly so if you apply the problem to proper names. It is not the case that the letters J-O-H-N can be simply converted into the "corresponding" Chinese or Arabic "letters", because these are vastly different writing systems. For the converse problem, for example, a Chinese person may choose a completely different Western name to use rather than a transliteration or translation of their original name.

Comment: You could use google sheets to get this done: https://www.jacknorell.com/using-google-translate-in-your-google-spreadsheets/

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you on explanation. I never had an experience before with this kind of solutions. I really thought I could use just converting letters from one language to another.